# How to change the pagination and banner display in displaytag

Tags: displaytag

I am using displaytag to display table data it is working fine but pagination is not looking good so i need to modify it as my per my need i.e The pagination in displaytag will be looking like below on top of the table:

```
 198 items found, displaying 1 to 10.
[First/Prev] 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 [Next/Last]
```

But I need it at bottum of the table and it would be displaying as shown below:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 Next
198 items found, displaying 1 to 10.
```

If I click next it need to display like below:

```
previous 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 Next
198 items found, displaying 11 to 20.
```

If i click previous it need to display like below:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 Next
    198 items found, displaying 1 to 10.
```

After going through the document of display tag i found itthe page banner will be changed by changing the property "paging.banner.placement" but how to do this one i am not getting can any help?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the placement property like this in your display tag and then the banner will be at the bottom of your jsp

```
<display:setProperty name="paging.banner.placement" value="bottom" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Display tag provides three option to place the banner.

1- top (default)
2- bottom
3- both (showing on top/bottom)

This is how you set it up under `<display:table>` tag.

`<display:setProperty name="paging.banner.placement" value="bottom" />`